# Function using PHP that converts a base 36 string to a base 10 integer

Tags: php

Can someone show me how I would write a php function that converts a base 36 string to a base 10 integer without using the base convert function

the function should work like this

```
echo base36_to_base10('614qa'); //prints 10130482 
echo base36_to_base10('614z1'); //prints 10130797
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can improve your question

Comment: If you want to avoid the `base_convert` function, you might want to explain why. If this is a homework question, you should consider editing your question to include what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: OP did ask for "without using the base convert function" not that it makes any sense

Comment: Yes its an assignment but I'm new to php and I need a little help on understanding how I would go about this to solve a larger problem and I can't use base_convert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the native [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function:

```
echo base_convert('614qa', 36, 10);
```

or if you prefer:

```
function base36to10($value) {
  return base_convert($value, 36, 10);
}
```

If you can'r or won't use `base_convert`, this should do it:

```
function base36to10($value) {
    // check for correct input
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z]+$/i', $value) == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // reverse and change to uppercase
    $value = strtoupper(strrev($value));

    // converted value
    $converted = 0;

    // cycle on character
    for ($c = 0, $l = strlen($value); $c < $l; ++$c) {
        // if the character is a digit
        if (ctype_digit($value[$c])) {
            // convert directly
            $v = (int) $value[$c];
        }
        // else convert ascii value
        else {
            $v = ord($value[$c]) - 55; // -55 == 10 - 65
        }

        // add to converted
        $converted += $v * pow(36, $c);
    }

    // now return
    return $converted;
}
```

Comment: While your answer works, the original poster did ask for a way *without* `base_convert`

Comment: @Xorifelse oh my, you are right! Editing on the way...

Comment: its a dumb restriction, so should be ignored unless its explianed

Comment: Why not convert it to upper care with -55? CPU wise it's more efficient as capitalized are in front of the lower case alphabet. Further more, works as expected and an up vote for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, why upper case would be better, except for different constant to subtract?

Comment: While I understand your question its too elaborate to explain in a comment. in PHP performance wise it's faster to convert capital to lower case, however `ord` is faster the other way around. Since you loop it, it is here where you win performance. Perform a benchmark and you will see.

Comment: I think I understand, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different option using a array of symbols:

```
function base36_to_base10($input) {
    $symbols = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'
        ,'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

    //flip the array so symbols are keys (or just write it that way to begin with)
    $symbols = array_flip($symbols);

    // reverse input string and convert to array
    // (reversing the string simplifies incrementing place value as you iterate it)
    $x = str_split(strrev($input));

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($x as $place => $symbol) {
        // increment sum with base 10 representation of base 36 place value
        $sum += $symbols[$symbol] * pow(36, $place);
        // or with PHP 5.6+ 
        //$sum += $symbols[$symbol] * 36 ** $place;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

How it works with one of your examples:

```
reverse input = 614qa -> aq416 
initialize sum = 0
a -> 10, 10 * 36^0 = 10, sum + 10 = 10
q -> 26, 26 * 36^1 = 936, sum + 936 = 946
4 -> 4,  4  * 36^2 = 5184, sum + 5184 = 6130
1 -> 1,  1  * 36^3 = 46656, sum + 46656 = 52786
6 -> 6,  6  * 36^4 = 10077696, sum + 10077696 = 10130482
```